# Need to write a program that asks the user to fill in a 2D array then checks how many times a digit between 0 and 9 was entered in those two rows

Tags: c, arrays

**This was a deleted question but I remade it so it easier for this community to understand what I'm asking

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main()
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int x;
    int y;
    int i = 9;
    int count[i];


    printf("Enter the size of your array: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    int arr[row][col];

    //This will read the rows
    for (int x = 0; x < row; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y) {
            printf("Enter row %d: ", x);
            scanf("%d", &arr[x][y]);
        }
    }

    //This will create a count for the rows
    for (x = 0;  x < row; ++x) {
        for (y = 0; y < col; ++y) {
            ++count[arr[x][y]];
        }
    }

    //This will count if digits repeat in the rows and print it
    printf("\nTotal count for each digit:\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
        printf("Digit %d occurs %d time%s\n", j, count[j], count[j] > 1 ? "s" : ""); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes on the code

I made i = 9 because the max number the user should enter is 9
On the "This will read the rows" there should be two printf's
"Enter Row 0"
"Enter Row 1"
How would I go and make it so the user would enter a set of numbers for the user to enter in both the rows. When I compile it just keeps saying "enter row 0: enter row 0: enter row 0". The program should find out how many times a number between 0 and 9 was entered. The final result should look like this

> Enter the size of your array: 2 6
>
> Enter row 0: 0 1 2 3 4 5
>
> Enter row 1: 0 1 6 7 8 9
>
> Total count for each digit:
>
> Digit 0 occurs 2 times
>
> Digit 1 occurs 2 times
>
> Digit 2 occurs 1 time
>
> Digit 3 occurs 1 time

ect. This would keep going until it the program hits "Digit 9 occurs however many times.

When I compile without the printf it runs through 3 rows when it should be 2 and most of the numbers that the compiler gives out are wack except for 2 digits

Ex The Digit 1 occurs 3 times

Digit 2 occurs -343589435 times

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `int count[i];` --> `int count[10] = {0};`

Comment: Wow that worked would you mind explaining what that did and why it worked?

Comment: Ten elements(0..9) are required and must be initialized with `0`.

Comment: So I was getting random numbers because all those numbers were initialized to random numbers in memory?

Comment: Yes chrisHG. Declaring an array without initializing will have garbage value

Comment: @chrisHG In addition to that, You had access outside the array range.

Answer (score 0):

There are ten digits 0-9. So the array `count` should have ten elements. Also the array need to be initialized.

Either use an array with the size specified by a constant expression and initialize it in a declaration like

```
#define N 10

//...

int count[N] = { 0 };
```

Or use a variable length array and initialize it using the function `memset` declared in the header `<string.h>`
For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

int i = 10;
int count[i];

memset( count, 0, i * sizeof( int ) );
```

Otherwise if the array is not initialized it will have indeterminate values.

Comment: Thank You, do you possibly know how to implement the 

"Enter Row 0"

and 

"Enter Row 1"

Comment: @chrisHG I have not understood your question. What is the problem?

Comment: @chrisHG Do you want to place the prompt before the inner loop like    
            printf("Enter row %d: ", x);
  for (int y = 0; y < col; ++y) {
                        scanf("%d", &arr[x][y]);
        }

Comment: So after I ask the user to enter the array size, the program should say 

"Enter Row 0"

then 

"Enter Row 1"

I got my program to kind of work but after I enter values for row 0, a new line comes up, would you know how to fix that?

Comment: @chrisHG and it asks, does not it? Or see my previous comment.

Comment: it does but after I enter numbers for row 0, I have to click enter twice for it to go to row 1

Comment: @chrisHG As I wrote place the prompt before the inner loop.